# Google Maps API v3 - how to make info window always opened up (Timemap.js )

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've being playing around with [Timemap.js](https://code.google.com/p/timemap/), trying to make the info window (item description) always opened up for an specific item (I mean, without having to click on it, always pop-up). For some reason, it's not working... I tried calling openInfoWindow function in different ways, but it doesn't work. It's just a simple/basic timemap.js code, the only "customization" I did is hiding the events from the timeline bands (noEventLoad: true), since I don't need/want them to be shown there. Here is my whole simple code:

```
var tm;
$(function() {


tm = TimeMap.init({
    mapId: "map",
    timelineId: "timeline",
    options: {
        mapType: "satellite",
        style: "classic",
        noEventLoad: true
    },
    datasets: [
        {
            id: "events",
            title: "Events",
            type: "basic",
            options: {
                mapFilter: "showMomentOnly",
                items: [
                    {
                      "start" : '2007-01-01T13:02:43Z',
                      "end" : '2007-01-01T13:20:55Z',
                      "polyline" : [{
                                  "lat" : 35.706,
                                  "lon" : -90.851681},
                                 {"lat" : 35.703682,
                                  "lon" : -90.84924},
                                 {"lat" : 35.697886,
                                  "lon" : -90.843138},
                                 {"lat" : 35.692091,
                                  "lon" : -90.837037},
                      ],
                      "title" : 'N487LP-1229',
                      "options" : {
                      "theme": 'purple',
                      "lineWeight": 2,
                      }
                    },

            ]
        }
    }
],
bandInfo: [    
    {
             width:          "00%", 
             intervalUnit:   Timeline.DateTime.SECOND, 
             intervalPixels: 10000,
    },
    {
             width:          "50%", 
             intervalUnit:   Timeline.DateTime.MINUTE, 
             intervalPixels: 100,
    },
    {
             width:          "50%", 
             intervalUnit:   Timeline.DateTime.HOUR, 
             intervalPixels: 300,
    }
],
scrollTo: '2007-01-01T13:02:43Z'
});
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't know anything about Timemap, so can't help with your problem.  However just wanted to point out that the trailing commas you have on the last items in each of your various structs and arrays will cause you errors in IE. Run it through something like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to see what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
tm.datasets['id'].items[0].openInfoWindow()
```

in which:

- `tm` is the Timemap-instance
- `id` is the label of the dataset(`'events'` in this case)
- `index` is the index of the item(e.g. 0 )

so call this after initializing the Timemap:

```
tm.datasets['events'].items[0].openInfoWindow()
```